# How to access a user's email after a gapi.auth2.authorize call

Tags: google-oauth, authorize

We allow users to optionally authenticate into our application using their google credentials via oauth.  This has been working fine, however google is terminating the google+ api call we use to get their email address which will be an issue for us.  Unfortunately I have struck out on finding the proper approach for retrieving the email so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the current code:
        
        
            var developerKey = 'our key';
            var clientId = 'our id';
            var scope = ['email'];
            var oauthToken;

```
        // authorize the current user with Google
        function authorizeGoogleUser() {
            gapi.auth2.authorize({
                'client_id': clientId,
                'scope': scope,
                'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthorizeCallback);
        }

        // handle callback from the authorization, doing the user lookup if valid
        function handleAuthorizeCallback(authResult) {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                //save the token and do the user lookup
                oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                getGoogleUserDetails();
            }
        }

        // lookup user details, prompting for authentication/permission if needed
        function getGoogleUserDetails() {
            if (oauthToken == null) {
                //authenticate
                gapi.load('auth2', { 'callback': authorizeGoogleUser });
            }
            else {
                //already athenticated, so continue to do user lookup
                gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', apiClientLoaded);
               }
        }

        function apiClientLoaded() {
//
// THIS IS THE PORTION THAT NEEDS REDESIGNED AS THIS CALL IS GOING AWAY
//

            gapi.client.plus.people.get({ userId: 'me' }).execute(handleGetUserResponse);
        }

        //do user lookup
        function handleGetUserResponse(resp) {
            if (resp && resp.emails.length > 0) {
                //get primary email address
                var primaryEmail;
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.emails.length; i++) {
                    if (resp.emails[i].type === 'account') primaryEmail = resp.emails[i].value;
                }

                //call server-side method to encrypt email and refresh page
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "OUR URL",
                    data: "{'emailAddress': '" + primaryEmail + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (retVal) {
                        if (retVal.d !== '') {
                            window.location.href = retVal.d;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the entire process, it now works for all browsers except IE.  Any suggestions regarding IE would be apprecaited.  Unfortunately IE isn't really throwing an error, it does the authenication but never returns to the listener.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var apiKey = 'our key;
  var discoveryDocs = ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"];
  var clientId = 'our client id;
  var scopes = 'profile';

  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API client and auth2 library
      gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
   }

    function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: apiKey,
        discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: scopes,
        'immediate': false
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
    });
  }

  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
                makeApiCall();
    }
  }

  function handleAuthClick() {
    // here is my current issue, need to see if the user is signed in or not
    var isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
    if (isSignedIn) {
        makeApiCall();
    }
    else {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }
  }

  function makeApiCall() {
    // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
    gapi.client.people.people.get({ 
      'resourceName': 'people/me',
      'requestMask.includeField': 'person.emailAddresses'
    }).then(function(resp) {
      var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0].value;
      //call server-side method to encrypt email and refresh page
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "our url",
        data: "{'emailAddress': '" + email + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (retVal) {
            if (retVal.d !== '') {
                window.location.href = retVal.d;
            }
        }   
      });
    });
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" 
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" 
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>

<asp:linkButton ID = "btnGoogle" runat="server" CssClass="LinkBtn BtnContainerVertical" Width="200px" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="handleAuthClick(); return false;" ><img src="../Images/google.png" class="LinkBtnIcon" style="height:20px" />Google Login</asp:linkButton>
```